# Calcite is unable to map cassandra column of type map having frozen set

Tags: cassandra, apache-calcite

I want to query Cassandra table using calcite. I am able to query other tables but I want to query table:

```
cyclist_teams1(id uuid PRIMARY KEY, firstname text, lastname text, teams map<text, frozen<set<text>>>)
```

When I query:

```
select * from "cyclist_teams1"
```

It is showing correct output for columns id, firstname, lastname but giving **null** value for **teams** column.

Can anyone help me in querying this table using calcite? Is there anything which needs to be done and I have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say that this is an error in Calcite, java driver should work just fine with that data...

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote the Cassandra adapter for Calcite, I didn't handle any columns with composite type. This shouldn't be too hard to implement in Calcite and we'd happily accept contributions to add this.